# (C++) Calling Function From Class Passed By Parameter

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, abstract

I recently stumbled upon a interesting problem. The problem is, in the clas Filter, i don't have any problem calling getKriterium().ohodnot().
But when I want to call it in for example Filter_FI(), it doesn't work.

```
class Filter
{
public:
    Filter() {};

    SortedSequenceTable<H, O> vyfiltruj(SortedSequenceTable<H, O> pVstup) {


        for (TableItem<H, O> *prem : pVstup) {
            if (splnaKriterium(O)) {
                table.insert(O);

            }
        }
        return table;
    }

    virtual ~Filter() {};

    void setKriterium(Kriterium<O, T>* pKriterium) { aKriterium = pKriterium; };
    Kriterium<O, T>* getKriterium() { return aKriterium; };


protected:

    virtual bool splnaFilter(const O& pObject, Kriterium<O, T>& pKrit) = 0;

private:


    Kriterium<O, T>* aKriterium;
    SortedSequenceTable<T, O>* table; 

};


template<typename O, typename T, typename H>
class Filter_fi : public Filter<O, T, H>
{
public:
    Filter_fi()  {};
    void setAlpha(T pAlpha) { alphaPARAM = pAlpha; };
    T getAlpha() { return alphaPARAM; };

    void test() {
        getKriterium().ohodnot()// Here I want to call the function .ohodnot(), But it will not let me...

    }


   virtual ~Filter_fi() {};

protected:
    virtual bool splnaFilter(const O& pObject) override { return (alphaPARAM); };
private:

    T alphaPARAM;

};
```

I would be very glad if you could help me fix the problem.

Comment: `getKriterium()` is a member function of the `Filter` class, that's why you can call it like that from within. `Filter_fi` doesn't know what `getKriterium()` function is.

Comment: So I tried adding `getKriterium()` and `setKriterium()` into `Filter_fi` but there came another problem. So I tried declaring `aKriterium` as protected. But the compiler said it doesnt't have access to `aKriterium` so after all that I even added attribute `aKriterium` into `Filter_fi`, it started working. But i don't know if it is an optimal solution.

Comment: `getKriterium` returns a pointer. Try `getKriterium()->ohodnot();`

Comment: Thank you for tip, but I already tried that. Didn't work..

Comment: What exactly is the error output? Other than that, little bit far fetched, but try `this->getKriterium()->ohodnot();`. Also, is the header of `Kriterium` included (sometimes one uses forward declaration instead)?

Comment: @Aziuth Well it did compile actually, but the IntelliSense says **No members available**. Guess I will see if it works on the actual implementation. I am currently working on "abstract level". But thanks anyway.